# Restrain the type while inheriting

Tags: java, generics, hashset

I created a java project to apply my GraphTheory course and enhance my java skills.

In this project :

I created a class `Sommet<S>`(Vertex in English) with an attribute Id with a generic type called `<S>`.

I created a class `Arc<S>`(Edge in English) with two attributes `Sommet`(Vertex).

I created a class `EnsembleArc` which is an `HashSet` of `Arc`

I also created a class `ArcValue` which inherit from `Arc` and have an int attribute `Valeur`(Value in English)

Here everything is fine and I dont have any problem.

But then I created a class `EnsembleArcValue` which inherit from EnsembleArc because every method from `EnsembleArc` will be useful to `EnsembleArcValue`.

But I also want `EnsembleArcValue` to be an `HashSet` of `ArcValue` (and I dont want an `Arc` which is not an `ArcValue`). And with the inheritance `EnsembleArcValue` is able to have an "simple" `Arc` in his `Set`.

So my question after all this explanation is : 
Is there a way for `EnsembleArcValue` to inherit from `EnsembleArc` but will only accept an `ArcValue` in his `Set`.

Here is an image of [The UML Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPMcr.jpg)
I hope it will help to understand my problem (dont look at the bottom).

Here is the code :

```
public class Sommet<S>
{
    //attributes
    private S id;

    public Sommet(S s)
    {
        setId(s);
    }

    public S getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(S s) 
    {
        assert s!= null: "Objet null passé en paramètre";
        id = s;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        boolean callback;
        if(obj.getClass()!=getClass())
        {
            callback=false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(((Sommet<S>)obj).getId().equals(getId()))
            {
                callback=true;
            }
            else
            {
                callback=false;
            }
        }
        return callback;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return getId().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getId().toString();
    }
}
```

```
public class Arc<S>
{
    private Sommet<S> depart;
    private Sommet<S> arrivee;

    public Arc(Sommet<S> dep, Sommet<S> arr)
    {
        setDepart(dep);
        setArrivee(arr);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String str="("+getDepart().getId()+","+getArrivee().getId()+")";
        return str;
    }


    public Sommet<S> getDepart() 
    {
        return depart;
    }
    public Sommet<S> getArrivee() 
    {
        return arrivee;
    }
    public void setDepart(Sommet<S> depart) 
    {
        this.depart = depart;
    }
    public void setArrivee(Sommet<S> arrivee) 
    {
        this.arrivee = arrivee;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        boolean callback;
        if(obj.getClass()!=getClass())
        {
            callback=false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(((Arc<S>)obj).getDepart().equals(getDepart())&&((Arc<S>)obj).getArrivee().equals(getArrivee()))
            {
                callback=true;
            }
            else
            {
                callback=false;
            }
        }
        return callback;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return getArrivee().hashCode()+getDepart().hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
public class ArcValue<S,V> extends Arc<S>
{
    private V valeur;

    public ArcValue (Sommet<S> depart, Sommet<S> arrivee, V valeur)
    {
        super(arrivee,depart);
        this.valeur=valeur;
    }

    public V getValeur()
    {
        return valeur;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class Ensemble<E> extends HashSet<E> implements Cloneable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4354387895748449845L;

    public Ensemble ()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Ensemble (Ensemble<E> ensemble)
    {
        for (E e : ensemble)
        {
            add(e);
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer("{");
        for(E e: this)
        {
            str=str.append(e.toString()+",");
        }
        str.setCharAt(str.length()-1, '}');
        return str.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Ensemble<E> clone()
    {
        return (Ensemble<E>)super.clone();
    }
}
```

```
public class EnsembleArc<S> extends Ensemble<Arc<S>>
{
    public EnsembleArc(Ensemble<Arc<S>> ensemble)
    {
        super(ensemble);
    }
    public EnsembleArc()
    {
        super();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4099925554493145279L;


    public EnsembleSommet<S> listSucc(Sommet<S> sommet)
    {
        EnsembleSommet<S> XSucc=new EnsembleSommet<S>();
        for (Arc<S> arc : this)
        {
            if (arc.getDepart()==sommet)
            {
                XSucc.add(arc.getArrivee());
            }
        }
        return XSucc;
    }

    public EnsembleSommet<S> listPred(Sommet<S> sommet)
    {
        EnsembleSommet<S> XPred=new EnsembleSommet<S>();
        for (Arc<S> arc : this)
        {
            if (arc.getArrivee()==sommet)
            {
                XPred.add(arc.getDepart());
            }
        }
        return XPred;
    }

    public void add(Sommet<S> depart,Sommet<S>arrivee)
    {
        add(new Arc<S>(depart,arrivee));
    }
    @Override
    public EnsembleArc<S> clone ()
    {
        return (EnsembleArc<S>)super.clone();
    }
}
```

```
//import java.util.Collection;
public class EnsembleArcValues<S,V> extends EnsembleArc<S> //implements Collection<ArcValue<S,V>> 
{
    //TODO faire en sorte que ensembleArcValués ne  contienne que des ArcsValue
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7163498825360866323L;
}
```

And you'll need this one to :

```
public class EnsembleSommet<S> extends Ensemble<Sommet<S>>
{
    public EnsembleSommet()
    {
        super();
    }
    public EnsembleSommet(EnsembleSommet<S> ensemble)
    {
        super(ensemble);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7278825382690341067L;

    @Override
    public EnsembleSommet<S> clone ()
    {
        return (EnsembleSommet<S>)super.clone();
    }

    public Sommet<S> firstSommet()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Sommet<S>[] tab=new Sommet[size()]; 
        return toArray(tab)[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: yes sorry i am not used to post my questions on forums, feel free to tell me if my code is wrong elsewhere once I add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this is to make the type of Arc you want part of your generic deceleration. Rename your existing EnsembleArc to AbstractEnsembleArc and change it's generic decleration from < S > to < S, T extends Arc< S > > i.e.:

```
public abstract class AbstractEnsembleArc<S, T extends Arc<S>> extends Ensemble<T> {
    // PUT ALL YOUR LOGIC CURRENTLY IN EnsembleArc HERE
}
```

Now create a new Class Called EnsembleArc and extend the new abstract class you've added, this new class will work identically to your existing EnsembleArc and class decleration should now look like:

```
public class EnsembleArc<S> extends AbstractEnsembleArc<S, Arc<S>> {
}
```

Finally have EnsembleArcValues extend the Abstract class instead of EnsembleArc so that you can declare that it should only accepts ArcValue and not simple Arc, do that like this:

```
public class EnsembleArcValues<S, V> extends AbstractEnsembleArc<S, ArcValue<S, V>> {
}
```

Comment: I'll try it when I'll have some time but I think it's exactly what I want, thank you.

Comment: It works perfectly, it seems I have to improve my generics skills. Thanks again.